# Sum time series with different time stamps MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongoDB database with multiple time series data and each time stamp is a separate document with some additional meta data from sensors. I want to sum the two time series in an aggregation but I am heavily struggling with that and can't find any examples.

Assume we have sensor A and B and the time stamps from the different sensors don't align. See an example of the data below. Next I want to sum the "volume" metric of the two time series. So for the example below sensor A has two time stamps en sensor B 3. So the sum of A and B should have 5 time stamps such that the sum reflects all the changes in the total volume (see also the schematic example below).

Anyone knows how to solve this in a mongoDB aggregation query? I can only use the mongoDB query language and not use NodeJS.

Sensor A

```
{
"_id":5d67d9ee074e99274eef30d5
"sensor": A
"volume":12.4
"temperatue": 20
"timestamp":2019-08-29 15:58:06.093
"__v":0
}

{
"_id":5d67da66074e99274eef30ea
"sensor": A
"volume":12.3
"temperatue": 21
"timestamp":2019-08-29 16:48:06.078
"__v":0
}

..etc
```

Sensor B

```
{
"_id":5d67d9ee074e99274eef30d5
"sensor": B
"volume":32.4
"temperatue": 20
"timestamp":2019-08-29 15:55:06.093
"__v":0
}

{
"_id":5d67da66074e99274eef30ea
"sensor": B
"volume":21.2
"temperatue": 21
"timestamp":2019-08-29 16:49:06.178
"__v":0
}

{
"_id":5d67da66074e99274eef30ea
"sensor": B
"volume":22.3
"temperatue": 22
"timestamp":2019-08-29 17:04:06.078
"__v":0
}

..etc
```

Here also a sketch of the result I would like to have.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // Determine start and end-time
  { $sort: { timestamp: -1 } },
  { $group: { _id: "$sensor", data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
  {
    $set: {
      data: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$data",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              [
                {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                    "$$this",
                    {
                      timestamp_end: {
                        $ifNull: [ { $last: "$$value.timestamp" }, "$$NOW" ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$data" },
  // find data per interval
  { $sort: { "data.timestamp": 1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: { $push: "$data" },
      timestamp: { $addToSet: "$data.timestamp" }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      sum_data: {
        $map: {
          input: "$timestamp",
          as: "t",
          in: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$data",
              cond: {
                $and: [
                  { $lte: [ "$$this.timestamp", "$$t" ] },
                  { $gt: [ "$$this.timestamp_end", "$$t" ] }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // sum up temperatures
  {
    $set: {
      volume: {
        $map: {
          input: "$sum_data",
          in: { $sum: "$$this.volume" }
        }
      },
      result: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$timestamp" } ] }
    }
  },
  // Join arrays to final result
  {
    $project: {
      result: {
        $map: {
          input: "$result",
          as: "i",
          in: { 
            timestamp: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$timestamp", "$$i" ] },
            volume: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$volume", "$$i" ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EbtIYIjho1S)